# What is the valid SQL query for the following JOIN problem

Tags: sql

I have the following tables

```
Customer (CID, name, address)
Orders (CID, BID, onDate, quantity)
Device (DID, title, IMEI, price, MID)
Manufacturer (MID, name, address)
```

What SQL statement would allow me to retrieve the ID's and names of all
the customers who have spent atleast X amount (lets say 350 for example)
on devices made my the manufacturer "Sony". The list should include the total amount of money spent by each customer on those devices.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you getting stuck at some syntax? Please add the snippet that you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the table `Orders` contains a column `DID` (`BID` is a typo, right?) that relates it to the table `device`.
Join the tables, group by customer to aggregate and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select c.CID, c.name,
       sum(o.quantity * d.price) total_amount
from customer c
inner join orders o on o.CID = c.CID
inner join device d on d.DID = o.DID
inner join manufacturer m on m.MID = d.MID
where m.name = 'Sony'
group by c.CID, c.name
having sum(o.quantity * d.price) >= 350
```

Comment: Yeah BID was a typo, it's mean to be DID (Device ID)
Thank you for the response, appreciate it!